# CodeIgniter mysqli connect error message (My first Q)

Tags: php, codeigniter

i got a bit of a problem here. I have a user that has a `BusinessId`. Now every business has its own database connection and users,products and much more. Now i want to show a nice error message when someone has a database connection that is incorrect. And everything should be fine when its not incorrect.
This is what i have.

```
if($databaseInfo != NULL) {
        $db_hostname = $databaseInfo['Hostname'];
        $db_username = $databaseInfo['Username'];
        $db_password = $databaseInfo['Password'];
        $db_database = $databaseInfo['Database'];

        $config_app = switch_db_dinamico($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);

        //$this->Product_shop_model->shop_db = $this->load->database($config_app, TRUE);

        if($this->Product_shop_model->shop_db = $this->load->database($config_app, TRUE)) {
            echo'Connectie success';
        } else {
            die("connection failed");
        }
    }
```

This is the error:

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'testnotrealbutwhocares'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>
> Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 201
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   /home/devmijnacc/domains/dev.mijn.iziaccount.nl/public_html/application/controllers/Product.php
>   Line: 44 Function: database
>
> File:
>   /home/devmijnacc/domains/dev.mijn.iziaccount.nl/public_html/index.php
>   Line: 316 Function: require_once

I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: use double == in your if. Here: $this->Product_shop_model->shop_db = $this->load->database($config_app, TRUE)

Comment: doesnt work. $this->Product_shop_model->shop_db is not suppose to be equal to $this->load->database()

Comment: alright, you should use a set function for those kind of assignments probably, and move it outside of your if for readability. Concerning the SQL error, where does it occur? or what does the message say. As you say in your title, there is an error right?

Comment: I added the error message

Comment: Have you tried putting it in a `try` - `catch` block to catch the error? If that does not work, you probably need to tell mysqli to throw exceptions so that you can catch those.

Comment: By the way, adding a `userId` in a column probably is a lot more efficient and scales a lot better than using a different database for every user...

Comment: @ZeroStrikerX Your access is being denied, so you probably have incorrect credentials

Comment: @ikdekker I think that is the point of the question: The OP wants to show a nice error message when the credentials are wrong.

Comment: @jeroen oh so its not really PHP then, but more of a css/html question? if thats the case: zero, please expand on what you would like to be shown.

Comment: Ive tried try - catch and i dont use a different database for every user but for every Business. And a Business has multiple users. I know the connection works if the credentials are correct. But i need to create a User Friendly message if they filled it in incorrect. (Every business can create database credentials that are saved on a different database for the webapplication itself) its kind of hard to explain.

Comment: Why dont you just output some HTML with a nice css class then just as you are doing now, except instead of the `die()` use `echo [some_html]` and if necessary an `exit;`

Comment: The code doesnt output anything as you can see its does a `echo'connection success';` or `die('connection failed');` but it doesnt do that at all. Thats mainly the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is within your question.
The user you are using to connect to your mysql doesn't have access.

> testnotrealbutwhocares
>
> Access denied for user 'testnotrealbutwhocares'@'localhost' (using
> password: YES)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. You guys didnt understand my problem really good.

```
 $db_hostname = $data['Hostname'];
        $db_username = $data['Username'];
        $db_password = $data['Password'];
        $db_database = $data['Database'];

        $config_app = switch_db_dinamico($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);

        $rr = @$this->load->database($config_app, TRUE);

        $connected = @$rr->initialize();

        if($connected) {
            $this->Webshop_model->createWebshop($data);
            redirect('settings/webshop');
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("connection_fail", "<div style='font-weight: bold;' class='alert alert-danger'>Webshop aanmaken mislukt! Kon geen connectie maken met de database van de ingevulde informatie.</div>");
            redirect('settings/createwebshop');
        }
```